# How to use Json Input option to do calculations in Kibana Aggregation Based visualisation

Tags: json, elasticsearch, data-visualization, kibana, kibana-7

I am trying to create a visualisation in kibana by calculating the other two fields. For this same purpose, we can use scripted fields but I heard that creating scripted fields can decrease the indexes performance(not clear).

[image: Json Input Field]

So I tried to use this JSON Input field to do the calculations, But it is showing this error.

`Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [script].`

this is the JSON script

```
{

"script":{

     "inline":"if(doc['prometheus.metrics.globalStatCapacityControlCallStpFailrePercent'].size()>0 && doc['prometheus.metrics.globalStatCallAttempts'].value >0){doc['prometheus.metrics.globalStatCapacityControlCallStpFailrePercent'].value/(doc['prometheus.metrics.globalStatCallAttempts'].value*1000000)}else{0}",

     "lang": "painless"

    }

}
```